# Is there anything wrong with sending other content along with a 404 error?

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

For example, day, in a somewhat REST-oriented environment, a request comes in for an object that doesn't exist, like:

```
GET http://example.com/thing/5
```

Is there anything wrong with sending back a 404 response who's body is the same as a a different page? For example, responding like:

```
404 body: [content from "http://example.com/thing/" which is a list of things]
```

Does it make any sense to do this? Will this cause any problems with certain browsers? Is it confusing to the user? Or is this perfectly fine to do?

Along these same lines, I would have the content of the 404 response match the request's accept headers as best I could. (ie. abide by content negotiation with the user agent)

For example, a xml or json request would get something along the lines of a simple error message and something that says "look here for similar things", while an html request would get an HTML page that has the error message as well as the content of the list page (as I indicated above)

Comment: I'm thinking long term that might be kind of hard to maintain, especially if you have (or might have in the future) a lot of objects on your site.  Also, it might be tough to redirect users to the "right" object that does exist based upon the many different ways a request may come in.

Comment: @ZackMacomber, The number of objects the site has won't have an impact on the list returned. That would be paged out so that it scales. Also, what other ways could a request come in for this situation? The URL points to one specific object, and it either is there or it isn't...I'm not sure I follow what you mean with "many different ways a request may come in"

Comment: I meant that an HTTP GET Request can be formatted in many different ways - just depends on how the client is formatting the HTTP GET.

Comment: @ZackMacomber, I still don't follow you. There's only one way a GET can be formatted...the spec defines it. Anything other than that is either a URL pointing at a different resource (_possibly_ the same situation as this), or a malformed request, which the base web server will choke on and throw back a 400 error.

Comment: Sorry - "formatted" might not be the right word - I mean like "GET http://example.com/thing/5", "GET http://example.com/thing/6", "GET http://example.com/thing/some_other_sort_of_request", "GET http://example.com/a_different_path/5", etc...

Comment: @ZackMacomber, Mapping the URLs to my controllers / actions is handled already (basic 404 for now), so that isn't an issue. It'a all programmatic, but the same sort of pattern would apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on how the Restful web services are being consumed. If I'm programmatically consuming the web service from a different application, then I would want the status code together and a plain text message instead of a message decorated with HTML tags. I mean, say for example, it doesn't make sense to return a bloated 404 content if your user makes the web service call using Curl because the message will not be readable to them.

You could have different "consumes" for each restful webservice. If it's an XML request, then you return 404 and a plain text message. Otherwise, you return the error page content.

Comment: The hope is to keep the service as restful as possible, and able to serve both Human-friendly responses and program-friendly ones from the same URL based on content negotiation (I updated the question to reflect this). The question is if having content in the response (of any kind) will cause issues or not. Will it make browsers choke, or will it be confusing to users, or to other consuming programs?

Comment: To answer your questions, the browsers will not choke if the response returns the content... and it will not be confusing to the users. I'm doing exactly what you described here (same url with different content negotiation) using Jersey. Basically I set different @Consumes to handle each type of request accordingly.  More advanced users will know how to set the right content-type before they make the web service call. Those who use browser to execute the call will see the HTML page instead of ugly XML or plain texts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with it.  In our webservice we always send back a json error object which includes stacktraces and other details about the response.  Even on a regular web server, you get at least text which can be displayed in a browser saying that you got a 404 response.